# Traversing a MeteorJS cursor with next() or prev()

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections, cursor

I've been using MeteorJS for a while and think it's a great stack. However, I'm having some issues with cursors.

I'm passing a `myCollection.find({...});` to one of my templates, I then want to start moving throughout this cursor based on time using `Meteor.setTimeout(...);`.

I have tried iterating the cursor with a `myCursor.forEach(...);`, that is fine, but I was wondering if there is any way to move through it with something like `myCursor.next();` or `myCursor.prev();`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.next()` or `.prev()` operator in Meteor for cursors. You can use the `skip` option in a `.find()` to skip a certain number of records in the results. This is useful for paginated queries, ex:

```
MyCollection.find(query,{sort: {name: 1}, skip: 20 })
```

would sort by name but give you documents ordered by name, skipping the first 20 sorted entries.

Otherwise for iteration over a cursor `.forEach()` is the way to go.